# Positioning circles

Tags: iphone, positioning, geometry

I'd like to position a given amount of circles in a field, whose size is also known. The circle's sizes can be freely choosen (although it should be >0). They may not overlap.

The problem: Performance is critical. Just randomly positioning them and reposition them in case they overlap is not fast enough.

My target is the iPhone, so I'm using Objective-C.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any specific requirements for layout?

Comment: It'll be nice if they had some space between them, but that's optional in first case.

Comment: No homework. Just being curious: Are there really some classes programming an iPhone? If I still had to go so school, I'd defenatly change to one of those :P

Comment: Stanford has iPhone coding class videos available for free online, in fact.  You might elaborate on your requirements for positioning a little bit.  You want the appearance of random distribution? You could start with a grid and then jitter the positioning and the sizing a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your circles by size, then lay them out using a [lightmap packing algorithm](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/lightmaps/default.html).